# TextView not visible until clicked

Tags: java, android, email, textview

I have to generate a layout according to the information the app gets from the network. Sometimes, it can have email adresses that I might need to truncate if they are too long for the space available.

My problem is that I can truncate them and fit them to the size I need, but they won't be visible until I click on them.. :S

Here's my code for my email textviews:

```
TextView noneText = new TextView(getActivity());
noneText.setWidth(width);
noneText.setSingleLine(true);
noneText.setTextSize(cell.getCSS().getTextSize() + 4);
noneText.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.NORMAL));
noneText.setText(cell.getText());
if(cell.getType() == AutoActionElement.AutoGridActionElementType.EML){
    // Email
    noneText.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES);
    noneText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
if (displayedAutogrid.getColumn(cellNo).isTruncated()) {
    noneText.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
    noneText.setLines(1);
}
noneText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | cell.getCSS().getGravity());
noneText.setPadding(noneText.getPaddingLeft(), padding, noneText.getPaddingRight(), padding);
layout.addView(noneText);
```

Thanks

**Edit** It works fine with phone numbers. They are truncated and display but not the emails....

**Edit** For now, I will change my method and simply not make the text clickable if truncated because there is a detailed view of the information where the email is stocked available. By viewing the detailed view, the email will show completely. Clicking on the layout containing some information (and the truncated email) will lead to the detailed view.
I'm still looking for an answer, not to use in my app but just for my Android knowledge!

Comment: Tried `noneText.bringToFront();`?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to application theme, i think that your are using v7 compact...
Try to use AppCompatTextView class or specify the TextColor...

I prefer inflating simple Widget from XML, to keep the application theme and avoid duplicate initialisation code for UI in JAVA.

create xml layout file: none_textview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:autoLink="all">
</TextView>
```

From Java code do:

```
TextView noneText = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.none_textview ,layout,false);
```

Comment: I get your point, but i really need to create new TextView programmatically since a cells in a same column could have different styling.. And the textColor becomes blue since I set it to link with email

Comment: You can create multiple xml or use AppCompatTextView instead of TextView on your code, or simply set the TextColor to your TextView...

Answer (score -1):

Did you put this code block in onCreateView ? If yes , you can try to put it in onCreate method.

Comment: It's in onCreateView but moving it to onCreate just shows nothing.